# Purpose of declaring `all` as .PHONY?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The GNU Make manual describes the following [use case](https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) of `.PHONY`.

```
all : prog1 prog2 prog3
.PHONY : all

prog1 : prog1.o utils.o
    cc -o prog1 prog1.o utils.o

prog2 : prog2.o
    cc -o prog2 prog2.o

prog3 : prog3.o sort.o utils.o
    cc -o prog3 prog3.o sort.o utils.o
```

It states that I can now just call `make` to remake all three programs. Which is fine, but I can achieve the same without declaring `all` as a prerequisite of `.PHONY` (as `all` is the default goal). Hence, my question:

Is the **only** purpose of `all` being listed as a prerequisite of `.PHONY` that I can still remake all three programs even if I accidentally, in the unlikely case, create a file in the same directory named `all`? I would love to know other reasons if there are any, thanks.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: I'm referencing the exact section of the manual you are linking (see code snippet). I'm asking for further details than what is mentioned @tkausl.

Comment: The manual does say "to avoid a conflict with a file of the same name", are you looking for more details?

Comment: Yes. I know that is one of the use cases of .PHONY, but it seems like .PHONY provides more power than just avoiding conflict with a file of the same name. So I'm wondering if there was a better reason, specifically with `all` above.

Comment: The manual says, right up front: _There are two reasons to use a phony target: to avoid a conflict with a file of the same name, and to improve performance._  I don't know why you mean by _.PHONY provides more power_; what kind of power?  What makes you think that?

Comment: Something such as running makes within sub-directories efficiently (as mentioned in the same section of the manual). This is more a consequence of one of the rules stated, i.e. avoiding file name conflict, but it isn't exactly an obvious ability. I'm wondering if something similar applies here. Is there a non-obvious consequence of having `all` in `.PHONY`? I admit nothing directly suggests this, it's more of a curiosity.

Comment: Also, is my question unclear? I thought I pretty directly asked if there was a separate reason than the clearly applicable one listed in the manual. Even if the manual states that "there are two reasons..." is it not a good question to ask if there are any more that are used in practice?

Comment: @greenfrog, in the bit in the manual about recursive `make`, the role of declaring the directory names phony is simply so that they can usefully serve as target names, despite those subdirectories existing already.  The efficiency gain (for parallel make) is not from the phoniness, but rather from having a separate target for each subdirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the **only** purpose of `all` being listed as a prerequisite of `.PHONY` that I can still remake all three programs even if I accidentally, in the unlikely case, create a file in the same directory named `all`?

You seem doubtful, but yes.  That is the only purpose served by declaring `all` phony in that example.

As the manual section you linked explains:

> There are two reasons to use a phony target: to avoid a conflict with a file of the same name, and to improve performance.

That's it.  Both results derive from `make` not conditioning execution of the recipe for a phony target on whether the target corresponds to the name of an existing file, or if it does, on the timestamp of that file relative to any prerequisites.  It doesn't even look for such a file.  That's the full extent of the practical effect of declaring a target phony.

Note also that although the advantage of using `.PHONY` in an example such as the one presented may seem small -- why protect against such an unlikely event as a file named "all" being added to the directory? -- we do get questions here from time to time that end up arising from issues with (non-)phoniness.  So do yourself a favor, and declare your targets `.PHONY` when that's appropriate.  It's not hard, and it might just save you, your team, or your customers an incommensurate amount of grief.